# Powershell - Array Range from user input

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What would be the easiest way to get user input for an array range.

For example:

```
function MyArrayOfMachines {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Machine
    # What should I assign the $Range variable as?
    )
 # Hardcoded range. User should be able to enter the range
 $Range = 2..5
 for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i +=1)
 {
   $result = $array[$i]
   $output = $machine+$result
   $output
 }
}
```

The above function should take the input as the name of the machine and the array range. For now I have the array range hardcoded. When I assign $Range as [Array]$Range in the user prompt, there is a prompt for $Range[0] etc etc. But I would like the user the enter the range.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't this work? Unless I misunderstood your question...

```
function test($range){

$range

}

test -range (1..5)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But my use case is to accept input from the user  During the prompt for $range if the user enters (1..5) , wouldn't it be considered as set of strings and result in machine(, machine1, machine.,machine.,machine5 as the result?

Comment: @Sanjeev No, that would not happen. `(1..5)` will be seen as an array of integers. Try running the example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also accept the range as a string and parse it yourself:

```
   function Test
    {
    param($range)

    if($range -is [String])
        {
        [int]$start, [int]$end = $range.split('.', [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
        $start..$end
        }
    else
        {
        $range
        }
    }
```

The reason for the if / else is for cases where the user passes an actual range, as in manojlds answer, rather than a string to be parsed (like 1..5). This means you can't strongly type the param though.

Answer (score 1):

Make it two parameters:

```
function test{
    param ( [int]$st,
            [int]$end)

    $Range = $st..$end
    $Range
}

test 1 5
```

If they input the start and end of the range you can use that to create it dynamically in the function.

**EDIT**:

To get the range from a string, try:

```
function test{
    param ($Range)

    $NewRange = $Range.substring(0,($Range.indexof('.')))..$Range.substring(($Range.lastindexof('.') + 1))
    $NewRange
}

test 1..5
```

Comment: Yep. This works! Still trying to find if it's possible to get the range in one prompt instead of using two input prompts :)

Comment: Looking at other options, I would just go with using two integer variables $st and $end. Guess atleast this way user doesn't have to know about the format to enter the array range.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @manojlds, the range should be passed in as an array. Parsing a string limits the possibilities of what a user could enter. By using `[int[]]` you can force the user to specify an array of integers. This would also allow a user to specify a broken range such as `((2..4)+(6..12))` which is harder to allow for when parsing strings.

In your example I'm not sure where `$array` is coming from, and you only need one line to return a computed machine name.

```
function MyArrayOfMachines {
    param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $machine,

    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
    [int[]] $range
    )

    foreach($n in $range) {
        $machine+$n
    }
}
```

You could create a single machine name,

```
MyArrayOfMachines Laptop 1
```

a range of machines,

```
MyArrayOfMachines Workstation (2..10)
```

or a non-consecutive array of machines

```
MyArrayOfMachines Server ((2..3)+(5..9))
```

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear. I want the user to enter the range. For example, I run the function in the powershell window and type in the function name.C:> MyArrayOfMachines, now user is prompted for the prompt for machine and Range[0]. Range[0] doesn't accept (2..10) as a valid value. If the function is called with the arguments it works fine. But I want the user the enter the values for parameters during run time.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass a string and evaluate it:

```
function Test([string]$range) {
  if ($Range -match '^\d+\.\.\d+$') {
    $RangeArray = Invoke-Expression $Range
  } else {
    $RangeArray = 1..5
  }
}
```

Some minimal validation is done to ensure that the user cannot pass arbitrary code.